# Toggle textboxes using angular

Tags: angular

Have to show one textbox only at a time, if click on toggle need to hide first textbox and need to show second textbox. If I click again need to show first textbox and hide second textbox. Tried below, but unable to display one textbox onload itself...

HTML:

```
 <div><input *ngIf="text1"
  id="test1"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Textbox1"
/>
</div>
<div>
<input *ngIf="text2"
  id="test2"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Textbox2"
/>
</div>

<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

.ts

```
 toggle() {
    this.text1 = !this.text1;
    if (this.text1) {
      this.text2 = false;
      this.text1 = true;
    } else {
      this.text2 = true;
      this.text1 = false;
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hide-and-show-textboxes?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftypeahead-template.ts)

Answer (score 2):

You can use 1booleanItem

```typescript
toggle() {
    this.text1 = !this.text1;
}
```

```html
<div><input *ngIf="text1"
  id="test1"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Textbox1"
/>
</div>
<div>
  <input *ngIf="!text1"
  id="test2"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Textbox2"
/>
</div>

<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hide-and-show-textboxes-dzomii?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftypeahead-template.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Tried below, but unable to display one textbox onload itself

you can set the boolean of one of the text boxes to true:

```
public text1: boolean = true;
```

Using a single variable to track the visibility:

```
export class NgbdTypeaheadTemplate {
  public showText1: boolean = true;

  toggle() {
    this.showText1 = !this.showText1;
  }
}
```

and

```
<div><input *ngIf="showText1"
  id="test1"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Textbox1"
/>
</div>
<div>
  <input *ngIf="!showText1"
  id="test2"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Textbox2"
/>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah...I just realized it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Rajasekhar You can also refactor, see the updated answer.